# Logging a specific package in log4j programmatically

Tags: java, log4j

I have to deploy a web app and the the log4j.properties file is created by the client so I dont have control over it.
Their properties file is like this:

```
log4j.rootCategory= FILE

!-----------FILE--------------!
log4j.category.FILE=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.base}/logs/rcweb.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-2d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

And in my classes I do something like this:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MaterialController.class);
LOG.info("my log");
```

But the log file has never been created.

I did the test and changed the `log4j.properties` file and deployed it in my computer adding the following line:

```
log4j.logger.br.com.golive.requisicaoCompras=DEBUG
```

This works, but I can't use the file like this.

Are there any ideas?

Comment: To format your code correctly prefix each line with at least 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. My client's log4j.properties file was wrong, the first line should be:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, FILE
```

Comment: This isn't about doing so programmatically but through configuration in the log4j.properties file. It answer the OPs intent (clearly, they provided it) but doesn't mention how to do this through log4j function calls.